# Decrementing round number and check for results

Tags: php

This is a basic PHP problem and I probably could crack it in no time tomorrow morning, but today it's been a looong day, so...

I have a function that returns neighborhood name using Google Maps API. I noticed that neighborhood name is changing based on a round of the decimals in lon lat. When it cannot return neighborhood name it returns city name instead.

What I am trying to do is start with 12 decimal numbers and compare returned result to the city name and if it's the same, continue decrementing until the returned result is different.

Here's what I've got:

```
$rnd = 12;

function get_hood($lat, $lon, $rnd) {

    $get_API = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=";
    $get_API .= round($lat,$rnd).",";
    $get_API .= round($lon,$rnd);

    $jsonfile = file_get_contents($get_API.'&sensor=false');
    $jsonarray = json_decode($jsonfile);

    if (isset($jsonarray->results[1]->address_components[1]->long_name)) {
        return($jsonarray->results[1]->address_components[1]->long_name);
    }
}

for($i=1; $i<=$rnd; $i--) {
    if ($b->busCity == get_hood($b->lat, $b->lon, $rnd)) {
        echo get_hood($b->lat, $b->lon, $rnd);
        break;
    } else {
        echo get_hood($b->lat, $b->lon, $rnd);
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm going in circles and need a fresh look at this.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your loop is infinite!  you should change `$i--` to `$i++`

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki I think the decrement is correct - it's the starting and ending conditions that are wrong, based on the description of requirements (_start with 12 decimal numbers ... continue decrementing_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several problems with your `for` loop.  First of all, you need to start your loop with the `$rnd` and stop at `0` or `1`.  Second, you don't seem to use the loop variable, but always use the same `$rnd` variable every time.  Lastly, you use `$b` variable, but it's not defined anywhere (although I think it may be defined outside of the short snippet you included).

If I understand correctly what you want to get, then this code should get you there (note I had to define `$b` to test the code)

```
$b = (object)[
    'lat' => 51.123456789012,
    'lon' => 0.123456789012,
    'busCity' => 'Withyham'
];

for($i = $rnd; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $newCity = get_hood($b->lat, $b->lon, $i);
    echo "$i => $newCity\n";
    if($b->busCity != $newCity) {
        break;
    }
}
```